# Retrieve more data when ID row in php is clicked using AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax, mysqli

I want more php data to show when the row of $row->student id is clicked. When row->studentid is clicked, it should show the data as an ajax in the showmore div.

Basically this is the part of index.php code.

```
<div class="studentsinfo">
   <div class="studentpicture">
      <img src="images/chrissy.jpg" style="width:100%;height:30%;padding-bottom:none;margin-bottom:none;"/>
   </div>
   <div id="briefinfo">
        <?php require_once("db.php");
        if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id"))
        {
            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                {
                    echo "document id:" . $row->id;
                    echo "<br>";
                    $studentid=$row->student_id;
                    echo "student id:" . $studentid;
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "requested: " . $row->document;
                    echo "<br>";

                    if ($row->paidstatus != 1){
                        echo "payment status: not paid";
                    }
                    else if ($row->paidstatus = 1){
                        echo "payment status: paid";
                    }
                    /*echo "<td>" . $row->document . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='records.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Edit</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='unverify.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>unverify</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='comments.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>comment</a></td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->paymentamount . " pesos";"</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='paymentamount.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>set amount</a></td>";*/
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "No results to display!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="showmore> <!-- show more data here -->
```

So when studentid button is clicked, it will get information from id.php and return it here. 
Id.php is this:

```
<?php

// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');

// confirm that the 'id' variable has been set
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    // get the 'id' variable from the URL
    $id = $_GET['id'];

require_once("db.php");

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE student_id=$id"))
    {
            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
                echo "<tr><th>Document #</th><th>Student #</th>
                <th>Documents needed</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>
                <th>recorded comment</th><th>unverify</th><th>comment</th><th>payment amount</th><th>set payment</th>
                </tr>";


                    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
                        $studentid=$row->student_id;
                        echo "<td><a href='id.php?id=" . $row->student_id . "'>$studentid</a></td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row->document . "</td>";
                        echo "<td><a href='records.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Edit</a></td>";
                        echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row->comment . "</td>";
                        echo "<td><a href='unverify.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>unverify</a></td>";
                        echo "<td><a href='comments.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>comment</a></td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row->paymentamount . " pesos";"</td>";
                        echo "<td><a href='paymentamount.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>set amount</a></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo"<br><br>";
                    echo "</table>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "No results to display!";
            }
    }
    else
    {
            echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
    }}

?>
</div>
```

So basically, i want all the rows in id.php to show in the div of showmore as an ajax. please help.
How would i write the AJAX code to post the studentID when clicked and return PHP data by the studentid.

I think the AJAX jquery code will look something like this:

```
$.(#studentid).click(){
something here
}
$.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : 'id.php'
and soemthing else
});
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ajax with jQuery?  Give a single `<tr>` an id and perform the ajax request with

```
//... in your HTML put
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
//...
<tr id="rowId"...> ...
//...

//in your Javascript, put
$(function (){
  $('#rowId').click(function(){ //bind row click to ajax
    //send request for student data
    $.ajax({
      url:"getMoreStudentData.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:'rowId',
      dataType:"json",
      success: onStudentDataReturned
    });
  });    
});

//do something with your ajaxed info
function onStudentDataReturned(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Once you get that working, you just have to pick a way to make all your rows have the appropriate rowId, which will be sent instead of the placeholder `rowId`.

Comment: basically, i used the AJAX Jquery code to trigger click() to get data from id.php (where all the extra data is) but it doesnt seem to work with the code you gave. Could you be more specific? What i need is if a person clicks on the <div id="rowId">, it goes to id.php, gets all the information according to student id, and displays the data in the index file. the row of student ID is diplayed inside the row using mysqli.

Comment: So in the code, i need the student id to be passed on to id.php so i can get all data from mysql by student id. i'm very new to jquery and ajax so please help.